# How could I know if Connection.commit() succeeded when network down?

Tags: jdbc, commit

I assume Connection.commit() works this way:

1. App sends commit command to database.
2. database commits current transaction.
3. database sends committed token back to App.

Then if step2 succeeded and something goes wrong in step3 (maybe a network issue), then the App doesn't get the response, how could App know the transaction status? Is there a generic practice?

Comment: There is nothing in JDBC itself. In some database systems - if you have the transaction id - you might be able the check the commit state of the transaction. You could also consider using an XA transaction manager to use two-phase commits (assuming your database systems supports real two-phase commits). If a transaction prepared successfully, but the commit timed out, then the resource manager should be able to recover and retry the commit. You could also simply try to `commit()` again using a normal `Connection`, though this could yield exceptions, or it might not work in some JDBC drivers.